# Magento 2: "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" configuration does not working correctly

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, seo

I have a store with few categories. I want to have only one url for each product - domain.com/product_name.html. I don't want to have products URLs with the category path in them.

I set “Use Categories Path for Product URLs” to "NO", but when I am saving any category it is creating the Catalog URL Rewrites for all the products of that category i.e. one regular url (domain.com/product_name.html) and one for each category path (domain.com/category_path1/product_name.html)

(domain.com/category_path1/category_path2/product_name.html).

Magento Version: 2.1.5

Comment: have you found solution for this

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works. The setting “Use Categories Path for Product URLs” to "NO" will work as expected on every page(Shopping cart, Recently viewed, Crosssell/upsell, wishlist etc) except product listing page.

Comment: I have tested this right now but on shopping cart page same product url showing (domain.com/category_path1/product_name.html) which is unexpected.

Comment: run indexing, clear cache.

Comment: There is no url_rewrite indexer in magento 2 but still did reindexing and clean as well as flushed magento cache, nothing changed.

Comment: This setting not working on Product Listing pages makes no sense.  That's the only place I would expect it to have any effect.  Did you figure anything out with this?  I have this setting turned off too yet it's still generating rewrites I don't want.

Comment: any solution for this